# Using MySQL Database Triggers

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-trigger

I have three tables: `users`, `account` and `accountinfo` and I am trying to make a trigger that will add the id from users to the `UserID` column in the account table. Here is what I tried:

```
CREATE TRIGGER catchUser BEFORE INSERT ON defaultdatabase.users 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO defaultdatabase.account(UserID) VALUES (new.id);
END
```

However, I get an error right after my `INSERT` statement that says,

```
Syntax Error: insert 'semicolon'
```

Why am I getting this error is I have the semicolon or is my trigger just wrong?

I'm using MySQL 5.6 if that makes any difference as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the delimiter:

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER catchUser BEFORE INSERT ON defaultdatabase.users 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO defaultdatabase.account(UserID) VALUES (new.id);
END; //
delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER catchUser BEFORE INSERT ON defaultdatabase.users 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO defaultdatabase.account(UserID) VALUES (new.id)
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please insert a semicolon after END.